# Export To Excel Fom DataGrid sharp Windows Application

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export to Excel from gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109585/export-to-excel-from-gridview)
>   [Export data from Datagrid containing the link button to MS-Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714470/export-data-from-datagrid-containing-the-link-button-to-ms-excel)

How can export DataGrids' contents to Excel using C# for a Window based application?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714470/export-data-from-datagrid-containing-the-link-button-to-ms-excel